# I think [illegal] is not legal on SO

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

As [illegal](/questions/tagged/illegal) does not define any category, technology etc., and its a general term, I think it should be deleted.

Comment: Agreed, this is not a good tag.  The 60 questions that now carry the tag should be reviewed so a more specific tag can be applied instead.  There are currently 7 other tags that start with "illegal".  More could probably be added.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[image: All hail Trogdor!]

Comment: It never gets old. Seriously.