# Should [tag:fatal] be removed from Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There are 109 [qualifying posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fatal) on Stack Overflow.

[fatal](/questions/tagged/fatal) is a general term.

I think it should be deleted.

Strangely enough, some users seem to use it as a synonym for error, although most use it in addition to error.

- Inspired by the burnination of [illegal](/questions/tagged/illegal) here: [I think [illegal] is not legal on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168380/i-think-tagillegal-is-not-legal-on-so)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree! However, I think this should be a half-burnination/half-retag. The tag [fatal-error](/questions/tagged/fatal-error) might be legitimate for some use cases. So use your judgement to decide whether to just remove the tag, or replace it with [fatal-error](/questions/tagged/fatal-error).

Comment: Should fatal-error be a synonym for error?

Comment: @GeorgeWBush: probably

Comment: A [tag:fatal-error] smells a bit like an [tag:unhandled-exception] to me.

Comment: @tchrist: That too.

Comment: @tchrist: Some languages do not have exception handling.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Very true. Especially ones like C.

Answer (score 4):

I've gone through the list of questions tagged [php](/questions/tagged/php) + [fatal](/questions/tagged/fatal) and there are now only [15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fatal) tagged questions left (mostly in [android](/questions/tagged/android) / [java](/questions/tagged/java)).

I don't know Java that well, but as I see it they can either be retagged [exception](/questions/tagged/exception) or [unhandled-exception](/questions/tagged/unhandled-exception). So if somebody from the Java tag could please clean up the last questions that would be great.

That would leave us with:

- [using static member of a class in .cpp file (c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984747/using-static-member-of-a-class-in-cpp-file)
- [KVM install and QEMU install (bios)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871776/kvm-install-and-qemu-install)
- [What is the difference between Perl modules autodie and Fatal? (perl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578042/what-is-the-difference-between-perl-modules-autodie-and-fatal)

Answer (score 3):

I would go with [fatal-exception](/questions/tagged/fatal-exception) as it is valid in [java](/questions/tagged/java) / [android](/questions/tagged/android).

I have fixed the  [java](/questions/tagged/java) / [android](/questions/tagged/android) posts. Now the [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fatal) remains.