# Different CSS behavior on tag hover

Tags: bug, tags, meta, design

Recently I [asked a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169914/the-im-human-button-in-the-captcha-page-on-data-explorer-site-is-editable) and in question content I used the tag status tag `completed` on mouse hover on this tag:

> [image: not working css]

while on the same tag on mouse hover in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169907/the-use-of-reputation-tag-on-so) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168380/i-think-illegal-is-not-legal-on-so) question in tag section I observe:

> [image: different css]

I think first one is inheriting wrong font-color.

Comment: The tags inside the post are inheriting the normal hover color from links (links on Meta turn red on hover), rather than keeping the grey color of the tag.

Comment: I think.... this issue has been fixed :)